# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

Hi thanks for reading this post,

I was developing an anonymous chat app using java and c. I decided to use jni for integrating c code into java. When I try to make a connection and send a packet, it crashes with the mentioned error. I searched too much online however nothing could solve the issue. I think somewhere in the C code I am committing a crucial access violation or jni code that I write has missing parts. Thanks again in advance for your great help. Here is the error message and code snippets involved.

Error Log File link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oy4k5uwz7mbyqiw/hs_err_pid13072.log?dl=0

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f21816b7d18, pid=13072, tid=0x00007f212eb1c700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b14) (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x6dfd18]  jni_GetStringUTFChars+0xb8
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/burhan/workspace/AnonymousChatApplication/hs_err_pid13072.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
/home/burhan/workspace/AnonymousChatApplication/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1039: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/burhan/workspace/AnonymousChatApplication/nbproject/build-impl.xml:804: Java returned: 134
BUILD FAILED (total time: 8 seconds)
```

The error output message

```
static {    
    System.loadLibrary("Send");
}  
public void sending(String ip, String message){
    int i=0;
    for(String s:splitMessage(message)){
        sender(2, ip, String.valueOf(i++));    // JNI NATIVE METHOD CALL
        sender(2, ip, s);                      // JNI NATIVE METHOD CALL
    }
}
```

The above section is the one that I called jni library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "ChatUtility_PeerConnection.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define MY_DEST_MAC0    0xFF
#define MY_DEST_MAC1    0xFF
#define MY_DEST_MAC2    0xFF
#define MY_DEST_MAC3    0xFF
#define MY_DEST_MAC4    0xFF
#define MY_DEST_MAC5    0xFF

#define BUF_SIZE    1500
#define DEFAULT_IF  "eth0"

struct pseudo_header {
u_int32_t source_address;
u_int32_t dest_address;
u_int8_t placeholder;
u_int8_t protocol;
u_int16_t udp_length;
};

unsigned short csum(unsigned short *ptr, int nbytes) {
register long sum;
unsigned short oddbyte;
register short answer;

sum = 0;
while (nbytes > 1) {
    sum += *ptr++;
    nbytes -= 2;
}

if (nbytes == 1) {
    oddbyte = 0;
    *((u_char*) &oddbyte) = *(u_char*) ptr;
    sum += oddbyte;
}

sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
sum = sum + (sum >> 16);
answer = (short) ~sum;

return (answer);
}
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ChatUtility_PeerConnection_sender
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass jClass, jint arg1, jstring arg2, jstring arg3){

    int sockfd;
struct ifreq if_idx;
struct ifreq if_mac;
int tx_len = 0;
int pack_Id = 12345;
    const char *peerIP = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,arg2,0);
    const char *message = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,arg3,0);
srand(time(NULL));
pack_Id = rand();

    char destination_ip[32];
strcpy(destination_ip, peerIP);

/* packet */
char sendbuf[BUF_SIZE];

/* zero out the packet */
memset(sendbuf, 0, BUF_SIZE);

/* ethernet header */
struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) sendbuf;

/* ip header */
struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) (sendbuf + sizeof(struct ether_header));

/* udp header */
struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr *) (sendbuf + sizeof(struct ether_header) + sizeof(struct iphdr));

/* data */
char *data = sendbuf + sizeof(struct ether_header) + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct udphdr);

struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;

char ifName[IFNAMSIZ];

/* Get interface name */
strcpy(ifName, DEFAULT_IF);

/* get data */
if (arg1 > 1)
    strcpy(data, message);
else
    strcpy(data, "Message Not Captured");

/* Open RAW socket to send on */
if ((sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) == -1) {
    perror("Socket Error");
}

int broadcast = 1;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof(broadcast)) == -1) {
    perror("Failed to broadcast");
    exit(1);
}

/* Get the index of the interface to send on */
memset(&if_idx, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
strncpy(if_idx.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ - 1);
if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &if_idx) < 0)
    perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");

/* Get the MAC address of the interface to send on */
memset(&if_mac, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
strncpy(if_mac.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ - 1);
if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &if_mac) < 0)
    perror("SIOCGIFHWADDR");

/* Ethernet header */
eh->ether_shost[0] = 0xAA;
eh->ether_shost[1] = 0xBB;
eh->ether_shost[2] = 0xCC;
eh->ether_shost[3] = 0xDD;
eh->ether_shost[4] = 0xEE;
eh->ether_shost[5] = 0xFF;
eh->ether_dhost[0] = MY_DEST_MAC0;
eh->ether_dhost[1] = MY_DEST_MAC1;
eh->ether_dhost[2] = MY_DEST_MAC2;
eh->ether_dhost[3] = MY_DEST_MAC3;
eh->ether_dhost[4] = MY_DEST_MAC4;
eh->ether_dhost[5] = MY_DEST_MAC5;

/* Ethertype field */
eh->ether_type = htons(ETH_P_IP);

/* Index of the network device */
socket_address.sll_ifindex = if_idx.ifr_ifindex;

/* Address length*/
socket_address.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;

/* Destination MAC */
socket_address.sll_addr[0] = MY_DEST_MAC0;
socket_address.sll_addr[1] = MY_DEST_MAC1;
socket_address.sll_addr[2] = MY_DEST_MAC2;
socket_address.sll_addr[3] = MY_DEST_MAC3;
socket_address.sll_addr[4] = MY_DEST_MAC4;
socket_address.sll_addr[5] = MY_DEST_MAC5;

char source_ip[32], *pseudogram;
struct pseudo_header psh;   

strcpy(source_ip, "1.2.3.4"); // Spoofed IP


/* IP Header */
iph->ihl = 5;
iph->version = 4;
iph->tos = 0;
iph->tot_len = htons(sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct udphdr) + strlen(data));
iph->id = htons(pack_Id); //ID of this packet
iph->frag_off = 0;
iph->ttl = 255;
iph->protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
iph->check = 0; //Set to 0 before calculating checksum
iph->saddr = inet_addr(source_ip);
iph->daddr = inet_addr(destination_ip); // Destination IP Address

/* IP Checksum */
iph->check = csum((unsigned short *) iph, 20);

/* UDP Header */
udph->source = htons(7777);
udph->dest = htons(7777);
udph->len = htons(8 + strlen(data));
udph->check = 0; //Set to 0 before calculating checksum

/* UDP Checksum Pseudoheader */
psh.source_address = inet_addr(source_ip);
psh.dest_address = inet_addr(destination_ip);   // Destination IP Address
psh.placeholder = 0;
psh.protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
psh.udp_length = htons(sizeof(struct udphdr) + strlen(data));

int psize = sizeof(struct pseudo_header) + sizeof(struct udphdr) + strlen(data);
pseudogram = malloc(psize);

memcpy(pseudogram, (char*) &psh, sizeof(struct pseudo_header));
memcpy(pseudogram + sizeof(struct pseudo_header), udph, sizeof(struct udphdr) + strlen(data));

/* Set the UDP Checksum */
udph->check = csum((unsigned short*) pseudogram, psize);

/* Final transmit length in bytes */
tx_len = sizeof(struct ether_header) + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct udphdr) + strlen(data);

/* Send Packet */
if (sendto(sockfd, sendbuf, tx_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &socket_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) < 0) {
    printf("Send failed\n");
}
else {
    printf("Packet sent! (%d bytes)\n", tx_len);
}
//return 0;  
     (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, arg2, peerIP);
     (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, arg3, message);
  }
```

Jni library function in C

Comment: Please create a [Complete, Minimal, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: But if I minimize the info, no one can understand what is going on. Even in the beginning, I had added the log file however it took more than 30k chars. So I trimmed it into this size.

Comment: I understand your concern, know that the http://stackoverflow.com requirement of a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example(MCVE) is a double edge sword. For the asker, it is common that in crafting an MCVE for the question they solve the problem. For everyone else reading the problem, it helps us value the question: If you've put enough work into asking a question that concisely summarizes the problem, we know that you and likely many others can't find a good answer anywhere else. That's the best motivation for people to provide an excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here:

> const char *peerIP = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,arg2,0);

Read about [JNI functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html)

Last parameter shout be pointer to jboolean, not 0.

Also if you use jni, `-Xcheck:jni` should be your friend =)

---

Ok, if you try

`jboolean isCopy1;
 jboolean isCopy2;
 const char *peerIP = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, arg2, &isCopy1);
 const char *message = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, arg3, &isCopy2);`

In your crash dump what will be on the top of native stack ?

> V [libjvm.so+0x6dfd18]  jni_GetStringUTFChars+0xb8

or not ?

Comment: I tried almost all the parameter combinations ( jboolean *, bool *, jboolean, bool) right now after seeing your post but it did not change. You are right to point out GetUTFChars' parameters as a cause however it still persists in not working

Comment: I tried that too, it still remains the same. It looks obvious that in the error message and log file  the error is made by GetStringUTFChars but according to oracle's docs I am doing everything right